# Correct use of firebase and @firebase npm packages

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

When I add a dependency to the [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) >9.0.0 package, `npm install` downloads both node_modules\ firebase and node_modules\ @firebase (without mentioning about it).

I know the @firebase is the [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scope).

I'm asking because

1. Only Firebase (Google) seems to do this, so why two packages?
2. Should one refer @firebase because the unofficial is dropped at some point?
3. The codebases look similar so there is a lot of duplicate code.
4. Update can break imports and change functionality, meaning is it now with or without @ and how should one know that, like:

`import { firebaseApp } from "firebase";`

`import { getMessaging } from "@firebase/messaging";`

`import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";`

Comment: Hey there! Did you figure out a solution for this? I have recently started exploring Firebase and this is something I got stuck into.

Answer (score 0):

[from npm  firebase/v/9.18.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase/v/9.18.0-canary.f8a2c5865)

> Version 9 provides a set of compat packages that are API compatible
> with Version 8. They are intended to be used to make the upgrade to
> the modular API easier by allowing you to upgrade your app piece by
> piece.

The "compat" packages in npm refer to compatibility packages provided by libraries or frameworks to aid in the migration or transition from an older version to a newer version.

The goal of these compatibility packages is to make the transition smoother for developers who have existing projects built using the older version (version 8) of Firebase. Instead of requiring an immediate and complete overhaul of the codebase to adapt to the new modular API, developers can opt to use the compatibility packages. These packages provide a bridge or compatibility layer that allows existing code written for version 8 to work with the new version 9 without major modifications.

in above npm link there is this usage:

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

By using these compatibility packages, developers can gradually migrate their codebase to use the new modular APIs provided by Firebase version 9. It allows them to continue using the familiar version 8 API syntax while working on migrating specific parts of their codebase to the modular structure at their own pace.